# How to access silent/vibrate mode for windows phone using C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I want to identify the current profile of windows phone.Is it is silent/ring.How can I check it.Please give suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with the current Windows Phone SDK.

You can vote for this API to be added to a future version of the SDK here: [Extend the API to query phone volume and vibration settings, maybe even set them.](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1908267-extend-the-api-to-query-phone-volume-and-vibration)

Answer (score 1):

As of wp SDK 8 you can't, nor can you adjust the volume or view/change current profile. 
[see this link](http://jwillmer.de/blog/2013/01/08/windows-phone-8-development-pitfalls/)

You can do these sort of things with [windows store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986967.aspx#custom_transport_controls) so perhaps it will come with the blue.

*Humm seems I took to long to post but as olivier stated its high on the wanted list*

*user1021583 have you thought about running back over your questions and marking answers? you seem to have a lot of questions and none are marked as answers*