# Windows phone profile control programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone and developing an app to change general to silent mode while reaching a place.
How can i access windows phone profile settings silent/vibrate? is there any way to change profile using GPS while reaching on a specific location?
Or is there any way to create a new profile settings and using these settings instead of built-in one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to access the silent, vibrate and volume settings in the current Windows Phone SDK.

Similair question: [How to access silent/vibrate mode for windows phone using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146997/how-to-access-silent-vibrate-mode-for-windows-phone-using-c)